# Is it safe to put multiple snitches and ex-cops in a dormitory?

Tags: prison-architect

My prison is getting quite large, and I have finally gotten past my serious issue of the "Unknown Reputation" inmates turning out to be snitches and ex-cops, by marking all that have unknown reputation as supermax and putting them on permanent lockdown in a dormitory with tapped phones. Eventually they use the phone and that almost always reveals their personality. So far, about 25-30% of the time, they turn out to be snitches, ex-cops, ex-guards, etc., that need protective custody. I started with a few PC cells (complete with all required amenities because I put them on permanent lockdown) but now I'm getting close to 20 PC inmates requiring cells, and having them all in separate cells is taking up tons of space.

To the question: **Is it generally safe to put multiple snitches together in a dormitory cell?** I'd make one for snitches, one for ex-cops/ex-law enforcement/ex-guards if that is the case. I've not yet seen a snitch or ex-cop be a "volatile" one, or some other attribute that would make me think they are a threat to others.

For reference, this is the PC/Supermax/Death Row section of my prison:

[image]

And in case anyone cares, this is the whole prison (some parts under construction of course.)

[image]

Comment: If you had followed my earlier advice of [tag:murdering] them all, you wouldn't have to worry about this. :)

Comment: If murder was an option, I wouldn't worry about it and just let the other inmates kill them ;P

Comment: As an alternative there is a "Snitch Sorter" mod that introduces background checks in the reception area - automatically adjusting prisoners who need protection to the correct category

Answer (score 3):

**It's safe.**  I have done this as a matter of course without any encountering adverse effects.

It seems that prisoners with vulnerable reputations themselves do not get involved with the targetted assassinations that take down snitches and ex-law enforcement (viewable in the intelligence screen when confidential informants are activated).

The only time I have had a problem was where one protective custody prisoner also had the volatile trait.  However, he most commonly caused damage and fought staff rather than fighting inmates.